# LinqToXML проблема при чтении дочернего узла

Tags: xml, linq, linq2xml

Есть xml следующей структуры :

```
<Заказ>
    <ДатаЗаказа>22.06.2016 8:10:55</ДатаЗаказа>
    <НомерЗаказа>666666666666666</НомерЗаказа>
    <ФИО>Мванова Ивана Ивановна</ФИО>
    <Возраст>50 л. 8 мес.</Возраст>
    <Пол>Ж</Пол>
    <Исследования>
        <Услуга>
            <Код>1990</Код>
            <Биоматериал>соскоб для посева</Биоматериал>
            <НомерИсследования>251088</НомерИсследования>
        </Услуга>
    </Исследования>
</Заказ>
<Заказ>
    <ДатаЗаказа>22.06.2016 8:20:05</ДатаЗаказа>
    <НомерЗаказа>666666666666666</НомерЗаказа>
    <ФИО>Мванова Ивана Ивановна</ФИО>
    <Возраст>28 л.</Возраст>
    <Беременность>
        <СрокОт>6</СрокОт>
        <СрокДо>7</СрокДо>
    </Беременность>
    <Пол>Ж</Пол>
    <Исследования>
        <Услуга>
            <Код>1905</Код>
            <Биоматериал>моча</Биоматериал>
            <НомерИсследования>250977</НомерИсследования>
        </Услуга>
    </Исследования>
</Заказ>
```

при чтении узлов следующим образом:

```
XElement codeElement = anElement.Element("Исследования").Element("Услуга").Element("Код");
            XElement maleElement = anElement.Element("Пол");
            XElement pregElement = anElement.Element("Беременность").Element("СрокОт");
            XElement localElement = anElement.Element("Исследования").Element("Услуга").Element("Примечание");
```

ругается на строку:

```
 anElement.Element("Исследования").Element("Услуга").Element("Примечание");
```

- Дополнительные сведения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
  Но! не ругается на другие конструкции,если он не имеет значения, причем проблема именно с этим элементом, подскажите, кто знает в чем может быть проблема ?

**Дополнение:**
[image: А он работает и не падает:)а если закомментировать строку с беременностью еще и выполняется]

Comment: Не верю. Ваш код должен был упасть в прошлой строке, а не в этой.

Comment: 1. В первом заказе нет элемента Беременность; 2. Элемент Услуга не содержит элемент Примечание

Comment: в конкретном примере нет Примечания, двумя строками ниже как раз идёт проверка данного элемента. И что, что он отсутствует в примере ? Ниже идёт проверка присутствие данных элементов, и если не подходит под условия то выбирается необходимая последовательность действий.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, объяснили ситуацию - сначала надо проверить наличие узла Беременность,затем наличие вложенного элемента.